# Linux RAID1 disk not booting in new PC - Gave up waiting for root device

Tags: linux, hard-drive, software-raid, raid-1

I had a Debian linux PC with two hard disks using raid1. Used is as DHCP and firewall. The raid1 consisted of two partitions, md0 as swap, md1 for / .

The motherboard in that PC stopped working, and I am now trying to transfer the raid1 setup to a new PC, "as is".

So I want to be able to boot into the new PC using my old raid1/disks setup.

When I tried to boot the new pc using one of the raid1 disks, I get the error message
"Gave up waiting for root device.
ALERT! /dev/disk/by-uuid/8c...e48 does not exist.
Dropping to a shell."

None of the similar questions on this site are about raid1 setup with this error so I made a new question.

I am not too advanced in linux (I was helped for the initial setup), but eager to figure this out.

Can anyone help me?

M

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this.

The problem did not seem to be the fact that I used the disks in a new PC. The problem seemed to be that the second disk of the raid setup was missing (one of the two disks from the old PC was damaged, so I did not connect it to the new PC).

Following instructions from here ([How to auto-start Degraded Software RAID1 under Debian 8.0.0 on boot](https://serverfault.com/questions/688207/how-to-auto-start-degraded-software-raid1-under-debian-8-0-0-on-boot)), I gave "mdadm --run /dev/md0" and "exit" at the initramfs prompt and debian loaded!

After I logged in Debian, I added a new disk to my raid setup (I used this as a guide https://www.howtoforge.com/replacing_hard_disks_in_a_raid1_array), and everything works.